# How do I report bugs for Trello?

Tags: trello

I am having quite a few problems with Trello at the moment, and my peers at work are finding the experience less than optimal.

I see a great future in this product and I would like to help in any way I can.

Where can I report bugs and issues, and or start conversations?

Comment: It seems a lot of these could be performance related, is that a known issue at the moment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just send an email to `support@trello.com`

We answer all email within one business day.

Please see https://trello.com/help for full information on how to see what we're working on, file feature requests, etc.

Comment: Thanks, the problems are mainly performance based at the moment (I think).

Comment: Now this is cool https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c

Answer (score 5):

Before you report a bug (or, especially, a feature request) to `support@trello.com` be sure to check out the [Trello on Trello board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) and see if your issue isn't there already.  You can access this board from the Trello on Trello link on the right side of the documentation (click on the book in the toolbar at the top).

If your issue is already there, you can vote for it, and add a comment as well.