# Does Trello support the idea of Tags?

Tags: trello

I see that I can add blank color labels to cards but does Trello support the ability to have Tags. I see on the Trello team's board there are cards that say "Bug" or "Feature" but I can't figure out if they are doing this through Tags and if so, how I can do this on my Trello Board.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can give the coloured labels meaningful names, which I've found really helps.

It's not entirely obvious how to do this, at first:

1. When viewing a board, click on the grey Icon just to the left of the board's name
2. Select "Preferences"
3. You'll see the labels with names like "Green (default)"
4. Click on the name of a label, a type in something meaningful, and save it.

Now, when you click on a card, and then "Labels...", the name you specified is displayed on top of the Colour swatch.

This at least saves people from having to remember the meaning you've ascribed to the different colours.

You still only get 6 colours to play with, though, and I don't believe that you can change the colours themselves.

Other nice tricks

1. If you are hovering over a card, and hit the letter L on the keyboard, it pops up the list Labels, which is rather convenient.
2. The "Filter Cards..." option at top-right allows you to use these labels for filtering.

**Edit 2011-11-19**

I've just noticed that there's now a shorter route to renaming labels: At the bottom of the list of labels, there is now a link to "Edit labels (sic) titles":

[image: Image showing "Edit label titles"]

Comment: I get a message saying that i need to be a board owner to edit the labels.  Why is that?  Also, can more than one person be a board owner.

Comment: I'm puzzled. In your question, you refer to "my Trello Board". Do you have a board that you set up, and it thinks you don't own? If true, that would be worth reporting as a bug - see [this question for how to report bugs](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18940/how-do-i-report-bugs-for-trello)

Comment: this is a board that my friend setup and invited me to it..  so I am using it but I didn't create it directly.  My friend IS able to edit label text

Comment: Shah - I knew I'd seen info about sharing board ownership somewhere. See [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18915/how-do-i-change-or-update-the-email-address-used-in-trello/18933#18933). If your friend follows the bit about adding a co-owner, you should be able to edit labels too.

Comment: Shah -> Ahah. I *love* auto-correct...

Comment: I've edited my answer, as I've just noticed a more streamlined way to edit the titles of labels.

Comment: Is this working for you guys, i can't change the name of the labels.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba It works if you are owner, or a co-owner, of the board.

Answer (score 1):

You can now display the names of the labels on the cards using [Chrome Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha/related?hl=en) because they are in the HTML. I used this CSS ...

```
span.card-label {
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    width: 65px
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```